# How can I get number of child windows for a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dom-events

I have one icon (say open) in home page. When I click on this icon one child window will be open and the icon in that home page is also changed to 'close icon'. When close this popup window the icon should be same as previous icon (i.e. open icon) in home page. It's working fine when I stay on the same page.

But when redirecting from home page to next page the entire page gets reloaded. And the default image (open icon) is displaying even if the popup window is opened.

Now my requirement is:

1. At the time of page redirection the image should be loaded based upon the popup window. i.e. if popup window is open it should display the **close** icon otherwise it display **open** icon.
2. If page is refreshed or redirecting to another page the reference of the popup window is removed. then how can I get the reference of that popup window in a redirecting page.
3. How to count the number of child windows for a browser

**EDIT:**

I have tried the following solutions:

1. I set cookie at the time of opening a popup window and reset that cookie whenever I have closed that popup window. But the problem is, at the time of page redirection if I close the popup window the cookie is not reset to it's previous value, because the page is still in processing.
2. same problem with the session variable also

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Set a cookie or a session variable when you open and close. This way you can remember the state of your popup window during new requests

Comment: thanks for ur reply, there is one problem if I set any cookies or session variable. The problem is when i open the window, at that time I set one session variable. At the time of page redirection I have closed that window. But the page is still in processing and session variable is not reset at that time

Comment: You could also use `localStorage`

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs in what way can I use localStorage, can you please explain me little bit more

Comment: @Pravallika69 you set save some data to it, just like an array: `localStorage['foo'] = "bar";`. You can save arrays too! The `localStorage` is visible across one domain. (need to rephrase that last bit)

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs but this is also create same problem what i have said above right?

Comment: @Pravallika69 Does it work if you check the `localStorage` on the master page load?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15171/discussion-between-pravallika69-and-starbeamrainbowlabs)

Answer (score 0):

When you go from one page to the next, you lose the reference to the pop-up window. But the pop-up window doesn't lose its reference to the main window. window.opener will always point to the window that opened it, even when there's a page change. Use this fact to reestablish communication between the windows after a navigation event. You might need to use an interval function to probe the main window, as I don't think you can listen for an event.

Comment: I have gone through many tutorials, I found that window.opener object is no longer available after page redirection or if the parent page getting refreshed. And I have to refer that child window object in the redirected page not in home page.

Comment: Are you sure? As long as the opener and the pop-up window have the same domain and the protocol matches, window.opener should remain. I think it might fail if call to open() had gone to a different web-site, as the object stored at window.opener would be tainted as belonging to the other domain.

Comment: Yes, in my code call to open() had gone to a different web-site

Comment: If you open() a page on your own web-site and have that page redirect to the other web-site, then you'll regain access to window.opener when the other web-site redirects back to a page in your domain. That's the trick, I think.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you, how can I regain access to window.opener? Can you please explain me how

Comment: I was just describing a situation where you might not be able to access window.opener even when the domain names match. Are these pop-up windows you're opening going to pages hosted elsewhere?